# Python - How do i know when a form button was pressed? (logout)

Tags: python, html, cgi

I'm trying to make a logout button for my website in python CGI. I was wondering how would I know when the button was pressed?

My logout form is as follows:

```
<form id="logout" method="POST" action="">
   <input type="submit" name="logout" value="Logout">
</form>
```

From here, i know that I need to store the form in FieldStorage so I did the following:

```
form = cgi.FieldStorage()
```

I've tried doing an if statement such as:

```
if form.has_key('logout'):
    doLogoutFunction()
```

but it doesn't work. Please help

Comment: First, define "doesn't work".  We can't guess what you're seeing.  Since you didn't provide all the code, we can't guess what other mistakes you've made.  Please create the **smallest** CGI application you can create which has this problem and post all the code along with a description of what "doesn't work" means to you.

Answer (score 1):

You need not do handing of logout via `POST` and also you need to point out to something in the action field for handing either `GET` or the `POST`

Here is an [example](http://webpython.codepoint.net/cgi_unique_field_names) which shows how to handle it via GET any form submit. You can simply allow clicking of the logout link to a particular portion in the url `/logout` and handle the GET that the location to log off from the application.

If you really want to do via forms, you can have a hidden field for the form and then verify the value.

```
<html><body>
<form method="get" action="logoff.py">
Name: <input type="hidden" name="hidden">
<input type="submit" value="Logoff">
</form>
</body></html>
```

And the corresponding CGI Python script as:

```
import cgi
form = cgi.FieldStorage() # instantiate only once!
name = form.getfirst('name')
if name == 'hidden':
   # do your action
```